# How to cancel TimerTask safely?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing the Android application and I use `Timer` and `TimerTask` objects for executing one task after particular time. But there is one problem - sometimes I need to cancel timertask, but if I do it that Android will cause an `IllegalStateException`. How can I cancel the task safely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reuse `TimerTask`s.

The reason why you get `IllegalStateException` is (most likely) because you try to schedule a task that has previously been canceled.

To do it properly, i.e. to avoid the `IllegalStateException`, you need to create a fresh `TimerTask` each time you want to schedule it.

Comment: Thank you for the right answer. Please, tell me, how can I check if the timer is running now? Because if i try to cancel timer but this timer has finished already I will have for the exception.