# Android - Timer class

Tags: java, android, timer

I am making an android app (QR code reader) and I need to do some action 4 times a second. I decided to use Timer class for this purpose. I discovered a strange behavior of it:

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(onTimer, 100, stn.GetStep());
timer.cancel();
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(onTimer, 100, stn.GetStep());
```

The last line throws an error - `java.lang.IllegalStateException: TimerTask is scheduled already`. Isn't it weird?

Comment: I solved it. I wrote "getTimerTask()" instead of "onTimer". getTimerTask returns a new TimerTask.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's how it is supposed to work. A `TimerTask` is a one-off object. Create a new `TimerTask` if you want to schedule the code again. (See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29).)

If you dislike the idea of creating a completely new object each run, you can do something like

```
Runnable toRunRepeatedly = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // your code goes here...
    }
};
```

and then do

```
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        // Delegate to the same runnable each time.
        toRunRepeatedly.run();
    }
};
```

**Related question:**

- [How to cancel TimerTask safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484538/how-to-cancel-timertask-safely)

Comment: I thought that 'new Timer()' creates a new thread, which has nothing to do with any other previous Timer instances (and threads).

Comment: Oh I see, TimerTask is not like method, it is an instance, which can be run only once ...

Answer (score 0):

SHORT ANSWER: No, not it's not weird.

It is a thread and it would be in the 'canceling' state, but due to the quick execution of the statements, the thread would not be cancelled yet. So it's not really weird, welcome to threading 101.

Why are you cancelling the thread to re-invoke it? What purpose does this serve? You are not giving the first instance time to safely stop before you call it again. You may want to set the timer object to null before re-creating it.